# Unable to download packages from a self hosted nuget server (404 error)

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, nuget

I installed a self hosted Nuget server as  described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).
I am using Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and Nuget 1.7.

From within VS I am able to see my self hosted packages in the package manager window, but when I try to install any of them, I am getting an error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found".

Help anyone?

Comment: How are you going about building the packages - through the command line or perhaps using a build server (e.g. TeamCity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hade to perform 3 actions in order to get this to work finally

1) Some of my packages has the extension ".symbols.nupkg" and I found out that the Nuget server cannot serve those packages only. If I change the extension of the package file from "".symbols.nupkg" to ".nupkg" everything works fine.

2) All the packages has to be placed flat under the packages folder (no sub-folders).

3) The packages folder has to be placed below the website (original location is fine, "~/Packages"). I tried to put it in absolute path "C:\NugetPackages" and it did not work.

Comment: Opened a discussion [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/357619#post842633) and an issue  [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2270)

Comment: Having already followed the other steps in this answer I found that switching the Application Pool from "Classic" to "Integrated" fixed the problem for me

Comment: A late update: We are now using the free ProGet (http://inedo.com/proget/overview) as a NuGet server. It has an easy setup and suits almost all our needs.

Answer (score 7):

please make sure in IIS to set the .nupkg extention mime type to application/zip.

See also these discussion for more info: [Issue #707](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/707), [Discussion #246387](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/246387)

Comment: Can't find the links, but this small answer has helped a bunch.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use IIS:

1. Allow directory browsing for the virtual directory where you have your nuget packages
2. Set the mime type for the .nupkg extension to application/x-msdownload
   That should fix your problem.