# NuGet.Server returns 404 error

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I have followed the [instructions](http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) to setup and host my own NuGet feed.  I am running the web application on a **Windows 2012 (IIS 8.5)** box.

I build and run the solution and get the default.aspx page...

Which says "You are running NuGet.Server v2.8.60318.667"
and "Click here to view your packages".

When I click on the "here" link I get a "404 - File or directory not found." error.

- I can successfully run a nuget.exe push command to put packages on
  the Nuget server; however I get a 404 error when attempting to run
  nugget.exe list command.
- I have restarted IIS and the server
- I have rebuilt the NuGet.Server web application from scratch.
- I have tried hosting the NuGet.Server    on a Windows 7 box with no
  success.
- The Web.Config has the following entry

  ```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  ```
- The web.config also has an entry to register the .nupkg extension as mimeType="application/zip"

It seems like the url routing is not working, but I can't seem to pin down what I am doing wrong.  Something is preventing the odata feed from working.

I know there are great 3rd party implementations of NuGet server, but I would really like to just get the free one working and it seems like it should be so easy. Any thoughts or troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer expands the comment left on [AndrewD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44388057/1204599).

Like him, I started out with a VB project and I ended up in the same camp as OP. What worked for me however was converting all C# code into VB, within these two files.

1. Default.aspx
2. NuGetODataConfig.cs (replaced this one with a new file: NuGetODataConfig.vb)

For the sake of completion, I'm including the post-converted contents of these files below.

---

#### Default.aspx

```vb
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="NuGet.Server" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="NuGet.Server.App_Start" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="NuGet.Server.Infrastructure" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>NuGet Private Repository</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Calibri; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>You are running NuGet.Server v<%= Gettype(NuGetODataConfig).Assembly.GetName().Version %></h2>
        <p>
            Click <a href="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/nuget/Packages") %>">here</a> to view your packages.
        </p>
        <fieldset style="width:800px">
            <legend><strong>Repository URLs</strong></legend>
            In the package manager settings, add the following URL to the list of 
            Package Sources:
            <blockquote>
                <strong><%= Helpers.GetRepositoryUrl(Request.Url, Request.ApplicationPath) %></strong>
            </blockquote>
            <% if string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiKey")) Then %>
            To enable pushing packages to this feed using the <a href="https://www.nuget.org/downloads">NuGet command line tool</a> (nuget.exe), set the <code>apiKey</code> appSetting in web.config.
            <% else  %>
            Use the command below to push packages to this feed using the <a href="https://www.nuget.org/downloads">NuGet command line tool</a> (nuget.exe).
            <blockquote>
                <strong>nuget.exe push {package file} {apikey} -Source <%= Helpers.GetPushUrl(Request.Url, Request.ApplicationPath) %></strong>
            </blockquote>
            <% end if %>
        </fieldset>

        <% if Request.IsLocal Then  %>
        <fieldset style="width:800px">
            <legend><strong>Adding packages</strong></legend>

            To add packages to the feed put package files (.nupkg files) in the folder
            <code><% = PackageUtility.PackagePhysicalPath %></code><br/><br/>

            Click <a href="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/nuget/clear-cache") %>">here</a> to clear the package cache.
        </fieldset>
        <% End If %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### NuGetODataConfig.vb

```vb
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling
Imports System.Web.Http.Routing
Imports NuGet.Server
Imports NuGet.Server.Infrastructure
Imports NuGet.Server.V2

<Assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(GetType(MGINuGet.App_Start.NuGetODataConfig), "Start")>

Namespace MGINuGet.App_Start
    Public Module NuGetODataConfig
        Public Sub Start()
            ServiceResolver.SetServiceResolver(New DefaultServiceResolver())

            Dim config As HttpConfiguration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration

            NuGetV2WebApiEnabler.UseNuGetV2WebApiFeed(config, "NuGetDefault", "nuget", "PackagesOData")

            config.Services.Replace(GetType(IExceptionLogger), New TraceExceptionLogger())

            Trace.Listeners.Add(New TextWriterTraceListener(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/NuGet.Server.log")))
            Trace.AutoFlush = True

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="NuGetDefault_ClearCache",
                                       routeTemplate:="nuget/clear-cache",
                                       defaults:=New With {Key .controller = "PackagesOData", Key .action = "ClearCache"},
                                       constraints:=New With {Key .httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)})
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: I started with a C# project and then did these steps and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you create a new empty *VB project* you will also get a 404 (in Packages and browsing using NuGet Manager).

You appear to have to create the project as **C#** and it works as advertised!

And yet the source code appears identical :(

Comment: I started out with a VB project and I tried this approach but it didn't work for me, though the idea stuck so I tried the opposite approach: I converted the existing C# code into VB, first in `Default.aspx` and then in `NuGetODataConfig.cs` → `NuGetODataConfig.vb` and it finally worked (upvoted). I added more details in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you name you project Nuget.Server, since your generated dll will be Nuget.Server.dll it will not work because Nuget.Server.dll is the actual dll for the server.
Rename your Assembly name to something else.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I made the mistake of trying to fetch the packages from http://[server]/nuget/Packages and got the same error. Removing /Packages from the end of the source URL was the answer, so http://[server]/nuget is the correct url.

Comment: After building my NuGet server and configuring it as a package source in VS I was getting `The V2 feed at 'https://nuget.myserver.com/nuget/Packages/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net451'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.` - this turned out to be the problem; that the server config in VS2017 NPM had a trailing `/Packages` on the URL that shouldn't have been there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have one answer not mentioned in either of the posts I've found. If you name your project Nuget.Server, even though publishing will work in IIS, ninject will fail to set up the package list route because it will try to load the wrong DLL and error out.

Here are some other possible answers:

[Possible Answers 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756944/404-on-nuget-packages-link)

[Possible Answers 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716156/unable-to-download-packages-from-a-self-hosted-nuget-server-404-error)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem today. Actually what I need to do is this in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    NuGetRoutes.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet.config file in either %APPDATA%\NuGet or $(SolutionDir).nuget may be referring to unexpected "active source" URLs.  For example, the nuget.exe brought by the TFS build agent install might be aware of NuGet v2 protocol only while the URLs refer to v3 protocol.  Or the custom NuGet server URL might be missing from NuGet.config.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue and I found a solution! I created a private nuget server following the instructions to create an empty ASP.NET project (I'm on VS2015) and then installing nuget.server (currently v2.11.3.0). I was able to run and see web page except I was not able to use "nuget.exe push" to upload packages. I got the dreaded 404 not found error.

I eventually cloned the nuget.server source code off github and ran that directly which worked fine!?  I discovered my `web.config` was incorrect. For me the key line was

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

in the

```
<system.webServer>/<handlers>
```

section.

I suggest anyone having issues should go to github and compare web.config files.

BTW: The `nuget.server` install is supposed to replace your `web.config`.  This may not have worked correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you get the 404 error when you try to upload fairly large nuget packages. I upped the `maxAllowedContentLength` and it helped.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31457280"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a clean `Visual Studio 2017` Web project.

Recreating from `Visual Studio 2015` and targeting .NET 4.6.1 sorted it out