# Nuget Server issue post migration to Win 2016

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I have migrated nuget repository from Win 2008 to Win 2016.
Alias to that server: http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed

Apart of windows, IIS is different as well, on the new server it is IIS 10.

After migration, nuget works pretty well, except one function. I can browse packages via web (http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed) or via Visual Studio etc. Visual Studio can see packages created manually.

The only problem is with the nuget push.

`>nuget push FEDivaNET.dll*.nupkg -Source http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed/ D568CD48-1609-40C9-9A5D-7ADC808129E5
    Pushing FEDivaNET.dll.3.41.73.nupkg to 'http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed/'...
    PUT http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed/
    NotFound http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed/ 128ms
    Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<>c.<PushPackageToServer>b__23_0(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<ProcessResponseAsync>d__181.MoveNext()`

- It is not a problem with the URL. When you try to modify URL then you will get different error
- It is not a problem with permissions to D:\MyServer\NugetPackages on  server, as I have set full permissions to that folder. I have also moved packages folder to different locations (ie. some other external network drive), but I am having same issue.

I tried compiling 2 different Nuget.Server versions: 2.14.0 and 3.1.2 ...Same exception.

Inside IIS, I am pretty sure I have set same settings as on the old server. Also I have INTEGRATED pipeline mode, so everything is good. I also tried setting authentication via technical users etc.

Not sure where is the issue, I think I checked every single setting. I tried with APIKEY, and without APIKEY. I modified every single setting in the Web.config, no luck…..

Comment: Have you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539179/nuget-server-returns-404-error/41680587#41680587

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that is not an issue. I tried playing with the setting, and also uploading small files... Same exception...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5350) an issue related to the error : you can try copy of binaries from bin folder to publish folder

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create website in IIS 10, then by default PUT verb is not allowed.

This can be set here:

```
IIS -> YOUR WebSite -> Request Filtering -> HTTP Verb tab: **Set PUT verb**
```

This has fixed an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The url on which push the nuget packet is something like

> http://{server}/{feed}/api/v2/package

So in your command use:

```
nuget push FEDivaNET.dll*.nupkg -Source http://xyz.mycompany.com/NugetFeed/api/v2/package
```

Documentation : [Publish a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I get same exception.
I also think that both suffix "/api/v2/package" is optional, on my old server it works with and without suffix.