# Own Nuget Server - The V2 feed at '' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, http-status-code-404, nuget-package, nuget-server

I created my own Nuget Server following the documentation and I got it, but I cannot access the packages from Visual Studio 2019 Community Nuget Package Manager.

So, when I do it through a browser I get this, which seems fine:
[image]

When I click on "here" to view the packages I see the test one I added, and if I click it I can even download it:

[image]

However, when I access by Visual Studio I get this:

[image]

The full error says:

> [Nuget Server] The V2 feed at
>   'http://*mywebsite*.com/NugetServer/Packages/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
>   returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'. But I can't figure
>   out why.

This is how I added it to the Nuget Manager:

[image]

This is the folder structure of the site:
[image]
[image]

As you can see the package test.1.0.0.nupkg is where the NugetServer project told me to put it.

I tried several things:

- Giving Everyone FullControl of the folder (because at the beginning I got 403 Forbiden instead of 404)
- Changing the folder structure, puting the nupkg package inside a folder named nuget, put the whole Packages folder inside the nuget folder and other things I saw as solutions in other Stackoverflow threads.
- Transforming everything to VB as [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539179/nuget-server-returns-404-error) suggested.
- Changing IIS parameters

Nothing worked for me, so I need a bit of help to find the way.

Maybe I need something for the "Search()" to work? I'm lost.

If you need more info I can provide, just ask, please.

Comment: Hi, please keep the URL of the Package Sources the same as the web link like `http://mywebsite.com/NugetServer/nuget` not Packages

Comment: You can not use the view package link and follow the guidance of the Repository URLs

Comment: Hi, did your issue still persist? Please feel free to let us know. Thanks

Comment: I followed the guide again from the beginning and now it works.

Comment: I'm not sure which was the problem with the other solution :\

Answer (score 3):

Please go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Nuget Package Manager</kbd> > <kbd>Package Sources</kbd> and check the resource is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing worked for me, so I need a bit of help to find the way.
>
> Maybe I need something for the "Search()" to work? I'm lost.
>
> If you need more info I can provide, just ask, please.

First, since you can get the nuget package and view the package on your local website according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server), I'm sure you have no problem with the steps to create your own nuget server.

The **main reason** is that you use the wrong link such as the view package in the Package Source. Instead, you should use the **Repository URLs** which is specified. The error is just it cannot

**Repository URLs**

In the package manager settings, add the following **URL** to the list of **Package Sources**:`https://xxxxxxxxx/NugetServer/nuget`.

**Adding packages**

To **add packages to the feed put package files** (.nupkg files) in the folder `D:\xxxxx\xxxx\NugetServer\Packages`

So please refer to the related info in your PC.

**Update 1**

**Sloution**

**1)** put the nuget packages into your local path like `D:\xxxxx\xxxx\NugetServer\Packages` so that you can access the packages through your links.(do not create any other new folders and put  packages into them)

**2)** change the package source to `http://xxxxxx/NugetServer/nuget` as Repository URLs in your PC saids.

**Update 2**

In addition, please do not forget to run the instance of the NugetServer project at the same time and when the first screenshot that you provided shows, you should follow the guidance of it.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: So, I added a new folder called nuget inside the NugetServer one and put the nupkg package inside.
.../NugetServer/nuget/test.1.0.0.nupkg.

I went to Visual Studio and update the Package Source to have as Source:
http://mywebsite.com/NugetServer/nuget/

Still got same error 404. I tried restarting VS, just it case, but nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. You should not  add a new folder called nuget and just put the nuget packages into `Packages folder` which is the default folder. The URL is just the address to get the package not a physical path

Comment: According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server) and from the interface after launching NugetServer project, we know that we should  add the new nuget packages into the local path like `D:\xxxxx\NugetServer\Packages` and then add the link `http://mywebsite.com/NugetServer/nuget` into package source to get them.

Comment: I'll check on monday and tell you. Thanks for keeping the track.

Comment: Now I kept the packages in NugetServer/Packages and the link to /nuget in Package Manager, but it still gives me 404. I tried to run the project locally and put the local path as link and it works fine, but of course this is not going to work when I set it up as a web server.

Comment: @serfe, in addition, l wonder if you followed [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server) to create a nuget.server. If you followed it, l think you should use the domain url as it said like `http://localhost:xxxxx/nuget`. From the picture, l found  that the `Repository URLs` and the `package source URL` are not the same, l wonder why you use the different. If you follow the  `Repository URLs`, l think it could work. If the document you followed is not this one, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT, facing similar kind of issue.Version used for nuget.server is 2.14.2 as the latest version facing problem with push. Able to push the package using "http:\\localhost:6000\" url which using url "http:\\localhost:6000\api\v2\package".
Configuring VS package manager with same url gave below error.

[Package source] The V2 feed at 'http://localhost:6000/api/v2/package/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm='NugetPackage'&targetFramework='net46'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.